# Longer response time when using dynamic variables in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, dynamic-variables, response-time

In my test plan written using JMeter, I have a create account request in which the username was generated via Random Variable config element. It was then passed to my next request which is updating the balance of the previously created account.

The problem is, I noticed that whenever I'm using a dynamic variable in the Body data, the response time of my update balance request plays around 1700ms to 1800ms but when I tried to set a static username (not using any variable), the response time was around 700ms to 800ms.

Is that a common behavior?

Comment: Actually this behavior come from your application and not from JMeter. Do you have some cache mechanisms ?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't make difference, the only thing I can think of is that each JMeter test element has its cost and using a hard-coded value is much "cheaper" operation than generating/calculating the value and if JMeter cannot send requests fast enough it will give you "false-negative" results.

Ensure that:

1. You're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. JMeter load generator(s) has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Disk, Network, etc, it can be checked using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)

Also it might be the case your application under test has [cached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) the "hard-coded" value related response on some level so no actual work is being made when you're hitting the same endpoint with same parameters for 100th time

Comment: I also noticed that the next request (update balance out) to the one that got 1700ms to 1800ms has lower response time. The only difference between the two is the value of a parameter. Is it because of caching as well?